# how do I configure postgresql to find the pg_controldata command

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to execute the `pg_controldata` command, I got the error *command not found*. Then I checked:

```
 ls -l /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/ | grep "control"
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   25960 feb  5 18:24 pg_controldata
```

Well, there is a `pg_controldata`, then:

- Why I got the error ***command not found***?
- What kind of configuration do I have to do to my postgresql or my sistem?

Please try an answer with a code or file configuration example.

Comment: Can you post the output of your command 'echo $PATH' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shell PATH environment variable is not pointing to your folder /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/.

In order to do this, use the command `PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/:$PATH"`.

If you want to automate this, you can add this line in your shell config file (ie. ~/.bashrc) with this :
`echo 'PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/:$PATH"' > ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: But that begs the question as to how the system works in the first place - how is psql run for example? I'm puzzled.

Comment: Also I had to run source `~/.bashrc`